# How to get React Router Browser history to work with the rest of my API endpoints

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, react-router

I am following the [React Router Tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/11-productionish-server)

Section 11 - Productionish Server.

I had to add this code to my server to get the browserHistory to work for the Router:

```
// send all requests to index.html so browserHistory in React Router works
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
})
```

Now all my other API endpoints are unnaccessable because of the `*`, but if I change it to serve on `\` the browser history breaks.

Server is written in Node. Any advice on how I can tell it to handle my api routes as well?

I usually mount my routes like so:

```
app.use('/api/v1/projects', ProjectsRouter);
```

Comment: Just make sure you add the `app.get('*', ...)` bit after all your API endpoints have been defined.

Comment: Wow that was easy... thanks!